# How to render a razor components with subcomponents without any parameters when functions wants to be passed a renderFragment

Tags: c#, blazor-server-side, bunit

I try to use BUnit for component testing in a Blazor server-side project.
I am quite new to this and tried to start a real simple setup:

```cs
using var ctx = new TestContext();
ctx.Services.AddTransient<IProposalService, ProposalService>();
var cut = ctx.Render<Proposals>();
```

Now I can't run this since Rider states:

> Method 'Render' has 1 parameter(s) but is invoked with 0 argument(s)

After this, I checked in the [documentation](https://bunit.dev/docs/providing-input/passing-parameters-to-components.html?tabs=csharp) how to pass arguments for this.
Since my component `Proposals` does not have any `[parameter]` tag in it only two injections:

```cs
[Inject] private IProposalService ProposalService { get; set; }
[Inject] private NavigationManager NavigationManager { get; set; }
```

So I though there might be some ChildContent missing, since I am using a `ProposalCard` like so:

```cs
@foreach (var prop in _proposalList)
{
   <ProposalCard Proposal="@prop"/>
}
```

referring to the section *Rendering a component under test inside other components* in the last section from the documentation link above.

Here they use the following code:

```cs
public class NestedComponentTest
{
  [Fact]
  public void Test()
  {
    using var ctx = new TestContext();

    var wrapper = ctx.RenderComponent<Wrapper>(parameters => parameters
      .AddChildContent<HelloWorld>()
    );
    var cut = wrapper.FindComponent<HelloWorld>();
  }
}
```

I tried like so:

```cs
var cut = ctx.Render<Proposals>(parameters => parameters.AddChildContent<ProposalCard>());
```

- the first render: Method 'Render' has 1 parameter (s) but iS invoked with 0 argument (s)
- the second render: Cannot resolve symbol 'AddChildContent'
- when I run the first render: ProposalTest.cs(35, 35): [CS7036] There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'renderFragment' of 'TestContext. Render (RenderFragment)'
- when running the second render: ProposalTest.cs (37, 35): [CS1061] 'RenderTreeBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'AddChildContent' and no accessible extension method 'AddChildContent' accepting a first argument of type
  'RenderTreeBuilder' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I thought maybe I have to create the renderFragment myself with `new renderFragment(..)` and pass it though I feel really puzzled with this right now and was not able to find any reference for this within the documentation which make it seem kind of a weird idea.

How can I make the render method work for my context here?

### update

it seems a little bit better but still now working
Though when I read the second exmpample from [here](https://www.telerik.com/blogs/unit-testing-blazor-components-bunit-justmock) I seems like I shouldn't be passing anything at all, since the are able to just call
`var cut = RenderComponent<FetchData>();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just had to call:

```cs
ctx.RenderComponent<Proposals>();
```

be cautious I overlooked that my IDE made the wrong suggestion for this

Comment: This is probably a good place to start: https://bunit.dev/docs/getting-started/writing-tests

Comment: Then, you can look at https://bunit.dev/docs/providing-input/passing-parameters-to-components

Comment: thanks I have already looked at this and got my first specs running :)